# How to save count down time to server in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, timer, laravel-5.5, countdowntimer

I am working on a online exam website build in Laravel 5.5 and Mysql as database where student can login and give online exams in a duration of time.

Suppose there is a exam that has duration of 60 minutes (3000 seconds)

Now what i did is to track exam countdown timer is that i am sending a request to server each second. I am doing this because if in any case network lost, power cuts or student turns off his/her computer intentionally then I'll have a track that student has consumed how much time (in seconds).

So next time when student start that exam on the same/different computer i can resume that exam with the remaining time.

This worked quite fine with less number of students.

But when there are 150 students giving exam together then server is getting 150 requests each second. So Server load is about 135 (2 CPUs). I checked it in WHM.

Let me inform you that my client is using VPS having 2 CPUs processor with 4GB RAM.

My client says that number of students can increase. But increase server configuration is not a feasible solution.

**So my question is how can i track the countdown timer and store that time on my server so that if for any reason exam stops then next time it can be resumed from the point it was stopped. No matter student is using same computer or not.**

Please guide me.

Comment: One option is to give each student a number between 1-5. Then you only update the time every five seconds. First the students with number 1, then 2  and so on, this way you have split the burden of the server by five and yet the impact is very little. If a student get 5 seconds more on a one hour exam it's nothing in my opinion

Comment: So if the student plugs out the net cable then he has more time for each question? Or what if he’ll tinker js code to give him more time? Not to mention net lag. I would track only start/end time on server side and ping once every 10 or 15 seconds to check if the test should pause

Comment: How does that give them more time each time? Keep in mind it takes time to load the questions again and find where you left off. In my opinion if will be zero net gain or possibly a loss @MichalBieda

Comment: Imagine if I'll wait for the question to load and then intentionally turn off my WiFi card - now the page is not sending anything to your server (the server pauses the test) and I have plenty of time to browse for the answers on my tablet/phone/book/whatever - then after a few moments when the answer is ready I'm reconnecting WiFi, put the answer down, load next question and do the same WiFi trick. Leaving logic on the client-side creates a hole for the cheaters IMHO but if you really want to keep it that way you could use WebSockets and ping over them/pause test on connection lost

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions but in order to save next question, page reloads. Also these tests are for evaluation after training sessions. So cheating is not a problem. I just want to show timer properly because after each question's answer submission, page reloads, then i need to set start time again. For this purpose i want that server should not hang. Because if server hangs then it does not set proper time. Please suggest me how i can send current timer time to server.

Comment: @VikasSharma, you got solution for this?